# AngularJS dont render html - Android 19 - 4.4.4 and Safari 8.0.5

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, dom, safari

I am developing an AngularJS app displayed in a Webview - Android.
It was working ok until yesterday. Angular sometimes is not rendering the DOM.
I was testing the app in multiple Android versions: API 19, 20... without results.

This is the code that initialize the webview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);

    // Clear cache
    mWebView.clearCache(true);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://demo.example.com");
}
```

If I run this webpage in a regular Chrome Tablet is working ok.
but the issue comes when it is desplayed into the webview.

I was searching help for a while.
Thank you so much.

**UPDATED:**
The same error happens on Mac OS Maverick Safari 8.0.5 and iPad too.
I think this is because a new update released both Apple and Google recently, that blocks AngularJS in some way...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** 
To identify the issue, I commented parts of my code until I see these very simple calls:

```
$("#modal-change").show();
$('#modal-confirm').modal('show');
```

In some way one of those jQuery/Bootstrap functions starts a conflict between AngularJS
 and jQuery and stop render the DOM when Angular need it...
Just replace it with my own functions and that's it.

I don't know if this is a perfect solution but it works for me and I post it if help someone.
Solved for me.